# what is the meaning of "Never is eternal"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have got a chance to read the above statement(Never is eternal) in a poster. But, I am not able to understand the actual meaning of it.

It would be great if you help me to understand the meaning of it.

Comment: It's a [band](https://www.beatport.com/label/never-is-eternal/68663) with minimal and techno underground sounds. It could mean anything, but of course "never" is forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is *eternal* it is *infinite* - lasting or existing forever, having no end (and in some applications, no beginning either).

"Never" means "at no time in the past or future; not ever". It is normally used as an adverb, but here it is being used as a noun for the *concept* of "never". This is called an *adverbial noun* and isn't unusual - for example, we use "tomorrow" as an adverb (eg "I'm leaving tomorrow") and also as a noun (eg "Tomorrow is another day").

Your phrase "never is eternal" is not an idiom I know, so is probably not a well-known quotation. It may be poetry, but as a statement, it does make logical sense, because "never" covers the past, present and future, and is absolute - so it *is*, I suppose, "eternal".